Combining standardizing and normalizing my input data for ML gives the best results, why?
When I combine standardizing and normalizing my input data for my hybrid ANN model, it gives the best results.
But I can't find anywhere, why. I based it on a paper's approach but they don't justify their practice either. Anyone knows why?
Standardization of my input data gives R2 less than 0.71, a higher RMSE and less stable results, than both standardizing and normalizing my input data.
